# Changing automatic font size in UILabel inside a View

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, font-size

I'm drawing a bingo card (UIView) with 27 squares: 9 columns x 3 lines. Cards can have 3 different sizes, so they must be resizable. And inside the card, every square with a number is an UIView with a custom class. Inside the view (in the .xib file) there is the UILabel, where the number is set with:

```
[lblNumber setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:((number < 10) ? @" %i" : @"%i"), number]];
```

When numbers have two digits (10->90) everything looks great inside the squares, but for numbers from 1 to 9, label displays with a bigger font size than the others because it only has 1 digit.
Ok, I tried to uncheck the "Adjust to fit" setting, but then font size remains small.
Autosizing settings of the label are set to both arrows, so the label has "space" to resize.

¿How can I have single digit numbers to resize the exact proportion than numbers with two digits?
As you can see in the line of code, I also tried to concatenate a space for numbers with one digit.

Thanks in advance.